# Function to shift down formulas

Tags: excel, vba, resize

I have a few formulas in the 1st row of a random table. I am trying to shift down / copy them to multiple rows beneath. Some of the formulas are copied, some of them remain empty.

Original Table
[image]

I tried resizing, but it doesn't work with a table.

Resized Table - The headers were copied, the formulas removed.
[image]

```vb
Sheets(destinationSheet).Rows(startrow + 1 & ":" & startrow + 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Formulas get copied in some of the columns and for the others I get blank cells.

I also tried with different code (within a loop for each row):

```vb
ActiveSheet.Rows(.HeaderRowRange.Row + .ListRows.Count + 1).FillDown '1st example
ActiveSheet.Rows(.HeaderRowRange.Row + .ListRows.Count + 1).Insert '2nd example

.Resize (ActiveSheet.Range(.HeaderRowRange(1, 1), Cells(.HeaderRowRange.Row + .ListRows.Count + 1, .ListColumns.Count + 1)))
```

The 1st example copies the formulas correctly for all of the columns, but overwrites the rows below (doesn't create a new row each time).
The 2nd example create a new row in the table, but copies only some of the formulas.

New sample table comparison
[image]

Comment: The same thing happens if I add another row in this table manually in Excel... Some of the columns are filled down properly, some are empty - without any formulas

Comment: Maybe have a look here to see whay I [Propose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57373789/11167163) Don't hesitate to give me feedbacks so I can help you. @dfhdfh

Comment: @Dorian, please see the updated code

Comment: Exactly... all formulas in all columns of row 1 - to next 10 or 20 rows below

Comment: are your formulas in the first row of your Tab On in the Header of your tab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this then :

The faster way would be :

```
Range("A1:A10").Formula = "=C1+B1"
```

Something slower..

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=C1+B1" 'Replace by your formula
Range("A1").Copy
Range("A1:A10").Pastespecial(XlPasteall)
```

You can alsoe use **FillDown** :

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=C1+B1"
Range("A1:A10").FillDown
```

**Note** : that the faster way would be the first proposition because which  autofills (FillDown) the range with the formula.

**Edit** In your case this would work perfectly :

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau1").DataBodyRange.FillDown
```

Change Tableau1 By your Tab Name.. Here `DataBodyRange` is used to select your table data.

**Edit 2** Without using `DataBodyRange`

```
Sub SelectTableBody()
    Dim rTableData As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Set rTableData = .ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
        Set rTableData = rTableData.Offset(0, 1) _
          .Resize(, rTableData.Columns.Count - 2)
    End With

    rTableData.FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: The formulas are way more complex and different for every column (30 columns).. Therefore I don't want to define them in the code... 1st row has all the formulas already, i just need to resize them for more rows below. The problem is that some of them work, some don't (similar formulas).

Comment: Thank you very much... For some tables the Databodyrange works fine, for others it keeps copying the headers instead of the formulas... All the tables have headers (checkbox yes for headers) so I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your table + circle where the error are ?

Comment: added the screenshot

Comment: Maybe try to do an other tab whith header and see what happen i bet that this tab got no defined header

Comment: If I create another sample table, the formulas are copied also over the header... Header definition might be causing it indeed, but to me the 1st row looks correctly set as a header.

Comment: Added another comparison screenshot of sample table... Looks like i am doing something wrong with the headers

Comment: Whan I will be back home i will explain you give me few minutes :)

Comment: The same table works in a blank workbook, but not in my workbook... Not sure where the issue is... I think the headers are defined the same.

Comment: @dfhdfh `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 6` What does this code Highlight In your tab ? Does it Highlight the header row?

Comment: @dfhdfh What about the **Edit 2** ?

Comment: Actually I found out that the databodyrange doeesn't work if the row totals are not defined.... I am trying to find a workaround, because I don't want them to show (because of the rowcount from another python script)

Comment: @dfhdfh Did you give a try to my **Edit 2** Which is not using `databodyrange` ? It might do the job ;)

Comment: Yes I did, doesn't add new rows and still copies the headers

Comment: @dfhdfh Thats really strange , I don'k know what is wrong here... Maybe Accept this answer and publish an other Issue with the code I gave you which is nicely working on my computer and explain what is the issue you are facing maybe other can help us... **Note that** this also work for you but on an empty sheet maybe something is wrong with the actual sheet..

Comment: If also add row specificaiton to the resize function then it does, but doesn't fill down all the columns, only few of them (tested with strings which work, static numbers don't work).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57407210/vba-table-resize-is-replacing-the-content-below