# VBA table resize is replacing the content below

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filldown the formulas in the 1st row of my table to multiple rows bellow that, but it's replacing the data in the cells bellow that. Ideally it should everything else down not overwrite it.

```
Sub SelectTableBody()
Dim rTableData As Range
Dim i, last As String

last = 5
For i = 1 To last
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set rTableData = .ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
    Set rTableData = rTableData _
      .Resize(i, rTableData.Columns.Count)
End With
Next

rTableData.FillDown
End Sub
```

[Table before resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLBsJ.png)

I also tried this code:

```
resizeSh.ListObjects(tablename).ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
resizeSh.ListObjects(tablename).DataBodyRange.FillDown
```

It's giving me error, that the code is attempting to shift cells in my table... Is there a way to change the 1st line to get the last entry in the table and then insert the whole row for all columns, not only the table?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Doesn't seem like you need a loop for this, i.e. I'm not sure you need 5 iterations to resize `rTableData`.

Comment: @BigBen I want to filldown the formula in the 1st row (some if statements and calculations referencing cells in others sheet - each row should reference the same cell + 1 row in the other sheet).... For some tables I want 5 more rows, for some 10, for some 7, depends.. That's why I have the loop

Comment: You don't need a loop to resize though. You can resize in one line.

Comment: Actually you should only `.FillDown` on the column your formulas are in. Otherwise you will filldown also the data. Please show a screenshot of your data. Actually if your ListObject is formatted correctly it should copy down the formulas to new rows automatically. Try the Macro Recorder and pull down the formulas manually, to get how the code would look like.

Comment: Only the resize will not do anything

Comment: It looks like you need to add list rows instead of resizing.

Comment: @dfhdfh You should look into the documentation what the [Range.Resize property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) actually does. It only resizes the "selection" (the reference) to a range. It does not move/insert anything in your worksheet. If you want to insert new rows you must use the [Range.Insert method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert).

Comment: I tried that as well... But then I get an error saying that the code is trying to shift cells in my table.

Comment: @dfhdfh You might benefit reading [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) there are [examples](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables#yui_3_17_2_1_1565250692208_950) how to add rows into a ListObject.

Comment: You need to insert rows under your table before trying to expand it. Or move the stuff underneath it.

Comment: You might try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57408629/11167163) I think it will solve your issue =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe give this a try :

```
Sub SelectTableBody()
Dim rTableData As Range
Dim i, last As String

last = 5
For i = 1 To last
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set rTableData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Tableau1").DataBodyRange _
      .Resize(i, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Tableau1").DataBodyRange.Columns.Count)
End With
Next

rTableData.FillDown
End Sub
```

[image]

After Macro's execution will give :

[image]

Comment: The problem is when I have one table below another one... See the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57430293/vba-inserting-multiple-rows-to-a-table-issue

Comment: @dfhdfh [Does This Help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57430732/11167163) Please leave me some **feedbacks** in comment to the new answer