# VBA Inserting multiple rows to a table issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert multiple rows to a table which has only 1 row at the moment ( fill down the formulas in the 1st row). The problem is I am selecting multiple rows where to insert new ones and the last ones are already in the territory of a 2nd table below it.

```
Sub RowsAction(ByRef targetSh As Worksheet, resizeSh As Worksheet, tablename As String)
Dim i As Integer
Dim last As String

last = targetSh.Range("A1", targetSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Count - 2
If last > 0 Then

With resizeSh
    MsgBox tablename & last
resizeSh.Rows(.ListObjects(tablename).HeaderRowRange.Row + .ListObjects(tablename).ListRows.Count + 1 & ":" & .ListObjects(tablename).HeaderRowRange.Row + .ListObjects(tablename).ListRows.Count + 5).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
End With
End If

End Sub
```

The code above will add 5 new rows to the Table 1. If I change +5 to +6 it will throw an error, because the last row will already be claiming Table 2's space. Ideally it would take the variable "last" but for testing we can use the numbers. The issue is I need to add the new row for the whole row of the sheet, not only for the table - so it would properly shift down everything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this to add Row to your table :

**Insert Row Above Row 5**

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add (5)
```

**Add Row To Bottom of Table**

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:= True
```

So For example to insert Several Row to your table you can do As Follow :

```
Sub Tryme()


Dim HowMuchRowToInsert As Long
Dim AferWitchRowShouldIInsertRow As Long

HowMuchRowToInsert = 10
AferWitchRowShouldIInsertRow = 3

For i = 1 To HowMuchRowToInsert

Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Tableau2").ListRows.Add (AferWitchRowShouldIInsertRow + i)

Next

End Sub
```

Lets test this :

File Before : 
[image]

File After :

[image]

So it does not distort the neighboring cells
**Edit 2**

```
Sub Tryme()


Dim HowMuchRowToInsert As Long
Dim AferWitchRowShouldIInsertRow As Long

HowMuchRowToInsert = 10
AferWitchRowShouldIInsertRow = 3

For i = 0 To HowMuchRowToInsert - 1

Range(AferWitchRowShouldIInsertRow + i & ":" & AferWitchRowShouldIInsertRow + i).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow

Next

End Sub
```

to avoid loop do stuff like this :

```
sub tryme()
Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Rows(“11:15”).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
end sub
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the loop... And adding rows just to the table won't shift down the entire row.

Comment: @dfhdfh This code will not add an entire row it will just add a row to the table selected here **Tableau2**

Comment: Yes, I know but I want the entire row, just in order not to distort the neighboring cells

Comment: @dfhdfh Look at my edit You will see that neighboring cells will not be impacted

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that I want to move down everything accordingly

Comment: So you want to add a line in the sheet and not only in the table ?

Comment: precisely, because otherwise i get another error: action is trying to shift cells...

Comment: @dfhdfh please give a try to edit 2 it will do what you needs =) it will insert before the third row in my exemple, If you want to insert **AFTER** Just replace `For i = 0 To HowMuchRowToInsert - 1` by `For i = 1 To HowMuchRowToInsert`

Comment: I used this option before, but was trying avoid the loop because it takes too much time (in some cases I have 40 tables, with 500 rows in each) - I just thought that it would work with a single insert of multiple rows.

Comment: @dfhdfh pls see the last edit and tell me if this help you

Comment: what to do if both tables have different count of columns? it throws errors. what is the workaround? inserting rows to the worksheet under the table itself? there must be something better I guess.